# Seeking website to share map via link including KML\KMZ overlays (which include images)

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-maps, overlay, kmz, service-recommendations

I wanted to overlay historic maps onto current maps\satellite imagery to share with others.

I overlaid them in the desktop version of Google Earth, and exported the layers as KMZ, but Google's MyMaps won't load them (saying 1 row couldn't be shown on map).

Are there any website where I could add them and then share a resulting link with others to view the overlays themselves?

Doesn't have to be Google Maps based.

Answer (score 1):

The website [Map Warper](https://mapwarper.net/) is exactly what you're looking for. Upload your scanned historical map. You can georeference it online and then overlay it on an OpenStreetMap basemap. Users can also download the georeferenced image to use it offline with their own software. Different export formats are available: GeoTiff, PNG, KML, WMS, XYZ Tiles.

That sayed, only constraints are legal ones. Be aware of copyright issues and make sure you have the right to upload the maps there.

*You can georeference the historical map online. Afterwards, the rectified image can be exported:*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess Carto.com is one of the best alternative to Google as they offer 3 public maps visualisations for free and you can load your KMZ here.

Answer (score 0):

You just go to GE Browser and then sign in to your Google account. I think it requires you to save it there and share. I am not sure but give it a try.

There is a left Menu and you just hit the three lines. Then look for "Projects". Hit the light highlight blue tab that says New Project with the down arrow. Hit the Import KML file from the computer.  In order to see it, you need to go to the settings. You may need to turn off the "Turn on 3D Buildings" as it might not be able to show 3D.

Comment: Well I'm a moron for missing that :-p  I had created a project, and there's no option to add KML inside the project as a feature, so I navigated right past there.  So the next question is... is there any way to share the map with the overlay?  The URL doesn't seem to include it, and I can't add the KML into a project that I can see, only export it as KML (yeah that doesn't help!).  Thanks so much for your patience and assistance!

Answer (score -1):

You could try the Google Earth online browsers. Don't confuse them with Google Earth Pro. This one requires you to login to Google and share with anyone. I haven't tried upload any imagery to that site.

Here is the info https://www.muo.com/tag/use-google-earth-browser/

Other than that, I don't know what else to share with your co-workers.

Though I have used it to review some of my work with the Elevation and Altitude for my old aerial photos with Agisoft Metashape.

Comment: Sorry, should've included in my question that I'd tried that, but couldn't find anywhere to overlay anything.  Years ago Google mapping was so open and useful and full of features... these days not nearly so much :-(

Comment: Today, I did played it around by adding KMZ to Google Earth browser and there was some sort of hard to have the layers to display at the same time...

Comment: You found a button in the web version to add KMZ?  That'd be great, I checked into the projects tab and such and didn't come across it (but I miss far too much)... I only have one layer at a time that I want to overlay, so that would be fairly useful to at least try... can you give this fool some insight into where the add KMZ button is!?! :-p :-p

Comment: Well I use Agisoft Metashape that I worked on many old aerial photography and that software has a tool that export the KMZ and you just add it in the Google Earth Brower but yes it only does one a time.

Comment: I have a KMZ that I made in desktop Google Earth... but how do you add KMZ to the GE Browser version? :)

Comment: Never mind, I already had a project created, so I was going right past New Project having it in the menu there.  Still trying to figure out how to share the map directly though :-/  Thanks for your help